# Understanding usage of TypeVar

Tags: python

When speaking about [`Generics`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#generics), python gives the following example:

```
from collections.abc import Sequence
from typing import TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')      # Declare type variable

def first(l: Sequence[T]) -> T:   # Generic function
    return l[0]
```

Could someone please explain what `TypeVar` does in this case? For example, if it can be anything why not just give it the value `Any`? And if it's constrained, why not give it a `Union` value? In other words, what is the usefulness of using `TypeVar(...)`?

I suppose in reviewing the above, it's used when an element of some sort of sub-element? For example, it could be:

```
[{set1}, {set2}, {set3}, ...]
```

And that type would be `Sequence[set] -> set`

But something like this:

```
[1, 2, 3, ...]
```

Would have type `Sequence[int] -> int`. Are there any other usages besides this "item-in-iterable"?

Comment: note `TypeVar` [is no longer](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.12.html#pep-695-type-parameter-syntax) needed [in Python 3.12](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#generics)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The purpose of the `TypeVar` in this context is to say that the function returns a specific type that is related to the argument's type.

For example, if you did:

```
a = first([1, 2, 3]) + "foo"
```

you would get an error, because in this expression `T` becomes bound to the type `int`, and so you'd get an error about adding an `int` and a `str`.

If you annotated `first` with `Any` types as you describe, this would not produce a mypy error (and hence you'd get a `TypeError` at runtime instead), because the return value of `first` would always simply be `Any`.

See the mypy documentation on generics for a lot more examples of how to use typevars: https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html

Comment: I see, yes I updated the question with a similar example. Is it useful outside of iterables?

Comment: Yes, typevars are useful in lots of places.  Any time you need to express a relationship between the types of two things in a type annotation (i.e. you don't know specifically what the two types are but you know they're related somehow) you probably want to use a typevar.

Comment: thanks for the link. Would you want to show one example (perhaps that you've used) where it's useful outside of an iterable in your answer?

Comment: Look at the `Box` example in the link for a (trivial) non-iterable example.  A more complex example (that I've used a lot in real life) would be type declarations for decorators, which are necessary to preserve accurate typing for the wrapped function.  If the reason **why** this is useful isn't readily apparent, it's kind of beyond the scope of a quick example to explain -- when you encounter a situation where you need it, you'll understand.  :)